# SharePoint Designer 2010 (Issue Tracking) created display forms do not display comments with history/log

Tags: 2010, custom-form

I am new to SharePoint Designer and currently I am working on customizing the Sharepoint Issue Tracking.

I have a comments column which I set the "append changes to existing text" = Yes. If I am using the default form (DispForm.aspx/EditForm.aspx), everything works fine and I am able to get what I expected as below:
[image: comments without problem]

However if I am using it in my customized display form, it shows the last comments only without showing the comments log:
[image: comments with problem]

Any idea which part that I have missing? Any feedback will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days of investigation, finally I managed to get it fixed by myself.

Below the tricks to get it done:

1) Find the line of code that references your Comments field (the text field with "Append Changes to Existing Text" turned on)

2) Replace the line that begins

> xsl:value-of …

and replace it with the following line of code:

> SharePoint:AppendOnlyHistory runat="server" FieldName="V3Comments" ControlMode="Display"/>

FieldName is the name of your field and ControlMode is the type of mode you're using to display the data (so if your form is in edit mode, you may want to use "Edit.").

3) Now you will see this history of this field with user and date/time stamped!